# loading images from array and showing one at a time

Tags: ios, arrays, image

I would like to show images in one image view and when an IBAction is called it shows the next image instead.
This is my code so far

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//init array with images what you have
   images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"IMG_2605.JPG",@"IMG_2627.JPG",@"IMG_2597.JPG",@"IMG_2613.JPG",@"IMG_2596.JPG  ",nil];
indexImage = 0;

}

-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
NSString *imageName = [images objectAtIndex:indexImage];
self.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    self.image1.image = [images objectAtIndex:indexImage];
indexImage++;

NSLog(@"B = 1");
}
```

Comment: And that's just enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the actual image, not the file name of the image. If these images are in your bundle, you can use the method imageNamed: to get the image:

```
NSString *imageName = [images objectAtIndex:indexImage];
self.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer. I am new to this, sorry. Yes my pictures are located in the supporting files folder. i have update the question with the new IBAction but i still get a breakpoint error on the NSString *imageName line, any ideas? many thanks

Comment: @user2196709, how are you declaring indexImage and images? You could put a log in the action method log each of those to see if one of them is nil.

Comment: this is how it is being declared in the .h file int indexImage;  // <= important..

    NSArray *images;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;

Comment: @user2196709, I see no reason why that should crash then. Do you get the crash the first time you click the button? Did you try logging images in the action method to see what it returns?

Comment: yes i do, im sorry i do not know how to do that. do you mean a Boolean in NSLog?

Comment: @user2196709, no I mean NSLog(@"%@",images);

Comment: oh okay, I placed that line in the IBAction but nothing shows in the output when the IBAction is called it just goes to debugger. thanks again.

Comment: @user2196709, did you put it in as the first line? If not, do that, and see if that gives you an output.

Comment: @user2196709, ok, then there's something seriously screwed up somewhere, not in the code you're showing. I can't offer any more advise without actually seeing your app.

Comment: thankyou very much. This may be a stupid mistake, but the uibutton is on top of the image view, should this be a issue?

Comment: @user2196709, it might be. Try moving it off, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: still nothing, thanks for your help. if your willing - how would i be able to show you the app?

Comment: @user2196709, I can take a look at it if you email it to me at rdelmar@comcast.net